# Disabling user from deleting text in tkinter scrolledtext

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

If this has already been posted and answered I couldn't find it by searching.
I am trying to use a tkinter scrolledtext widget to serve as a basic text display for file operations the script I'm writing will perform. Why would I want to do this? I don't like how the terminal limits how far you can scroll, how it looks, and I think this looks much more streamlined into a simple GUI.

I know we can create a simple scrolledtext widget like so and also disable user input and deleting with setting the state to `state = disabled`. Since these is just serving as a text area to display essentially what's happening I don't need any input from the user merely a read-only interface. However, setting the state to disabled prevents `insert` from being used to insert the updates themselves.

Is there a way around this? Simpler alternative methods are also welcome. I could use a label, but then I'd have scrolling issues.

I realize I could change the state before and after inserting, from normal to disabled, but seems like there should be a simpler solution.

```
  text_area = ScrolledText(master = root, wrap = tk.WORD, state = tk.DISABLED)
  text_area.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
  text_area.insert(tk.INSERT, some_text_here) #No longer works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the state from disable to normal, inserting text, and setting it back to disabled, is the simplest solution.